# Java replace all method appending the replacement string instead of replacing

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to replace all the words starting with vowels to `"XXXXX"` in my text file. I am using **`RegEx`** to perform this, but when I try to replace it with replaceAll method, my replacement string is getting appended instead of replacing.

Here is my text file, code and output.

Hello 12 I am John
How are you
I am good
Thank you 89767 0

## $%^

code:

```
String dest = data.replaceAll("\\b(?=[AEIOUaeiou])","XXXXX");
System.out.println(dest);
```

data is the string that contains all my file data.

output :

```
Hello 12 XXXXXI XXXXXam Manoj
How XXXXXare you
XXXXXI XXXXXam good
Thank you 89767 0
#$%^
```

Please help me out in solving this issue. I have gone through some answers regarding replaceAll() method but I am not able to find answer to my problem.

Comment: Use `data.replaceAll("\\b[AEIOUaeiou]\\w*","XXXXX");` or to only match letters, replace `\w` with `\p{Alpha}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern only contains *zero-width assertions*: `\\b` matches a word boundary location and `(?=[AEIOUaeiou])` positive lookahead asserts the position before a vowel.

Make the pattern *consuming*. Use

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\b[AEIOUaeiou]\\w*","XXXXX");
```

To only match letters, replace `\w` with `\p{Alpha}`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r7muyW/1) and a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/WUc4ac):

```
String data = "Hello 12 I am John\nHow are you\nI am good\nThank you 89767 0\n#$%^";
data = data.replaceAll("\\b[AEIOUaeiou]\\p{Alpha}*","XXXXX");
System.out.println(data);
```

Output:

```
Hello 12 XXXXX XXXXX John
How XXXXX you
XXXXX XXXXX good
Thank you 89767 0
#$%^
```

Comment: I have tried with \p{Alpha} but could not get the expected result     
 Input file : Hello 12 I am John
How are you
I am good ou%e
Thank you 89767 0
#$%^    String dest = so.replaceAll("\\b[AEIOUaeiou]\\p{Alpha}*","XXXXX");
  System.out.println(dest);   output:Hello 12 XXXXX XXXXX John
How XXXXX you
XXXXX XXXXX good XXXXX%XXXXX
Thank you 89767 0
#$%^ .

Comment: Yeah, it will [look like this](http://ideone.com/WUc4ac). Note you may append `\\b` at the end (`"\\b[AEIOUaeiou]\\p{Alpha}*\\b"`) to make it only match whole words.

Comment: @MANOJREDDY: Could you please explain what you expect for the string you provided above? [Maybe the expected result is like here](https://regex101.com/r/UKaxPk/2)? Then replace `\w` with `\S`.